# Не добавляется дата и время с датапикера

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

[image: datapicker]

Помогите отправить данные с датапикера
В phpmyadmin добавляются только нули

```
<?php
    include_once("bd.php");
    if (isset($_POST['datetimepicker'])) {
        $dataTime = $_POST['datetimepicker'];
    return  json_encode(['type'=> 'success', 'mess' => 'Ok']);
    } else {
        return  json_encode(['type'=> 'error', 'mess' => 'Not found']);
    }
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO datetime(dateandtime) VALUES ('$dataTime')");
    mysql_close(); ?>
```

код инициализации datepicker:

```
jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
    lang: 'ru',
    allowTimes: ['10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00'],
    minDate: 0,
  });
});
```

отправка формы:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'send.php',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (res) {
       console.log(res.mess)
    }
```

часть html:

```
<div class="container formcont">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 g9 col-lg-offset-4">
        <h2>Выберите время и дату</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 datetimepicker" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker" >
        <input type="submit" id="sybmitform"  value="Забронировать" class="btn btnnext"></input>
      </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: код покажите ....

Comment: @МаксимЛенский добавил

Comment: @pointmen23 покажите как Вы инициализируете datepicker

Comment: @Alex 
` <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');
      $(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            inline:true,
            format:'d.m.Y H:i',
            lang:'ru',
            allowTimes:['10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00'],
            minDate:0,
          });
      });
  </script>`

Comment: @pointmen23 проверьте входящий `$_POST['datetimepicker']`, к Вам приходит значение даты в виде `d.m.Y H:i`. На сервере конвертируйте в формат даты `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: @Alex а можете поподробнее объяснить?

Comment: @pointmen23 вообще глядя на код вставки вообще быть  не должно, т.к. в любом случае у Вас `return`

Comment: @pointmen23 покажите еще как Вы отправляете ajax(на какое событие он у Вас стоит), а также проверьте тот ли код php Вы опубликовали, потому что `return` вернет данные json в любом случае и mysql_query не будет.

Answer (score 0):

1) не видно что в ajax Вы отправляете данные. Он должен быть вида:

```
$("#sybmitform").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();//чтобы форма не отправилась второй раз через submit
  $.ajax({
    url: 'send.php',
    data: {datetimepicker: $("#datetimepicker").val()}, // прикрепляем значение поля datetimepicker к запросу
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res.mess)
    }
  });
});
```

2) т.к. формат даты в *datepicker* `d.m.Y H:i`, на серверной стороне нужно изменить формат даты на формат *datetime* в MySql, а именно в `Y-m-d H:i:s`

```
include_once("bd.php");
if (isset($_POST['datetimepicker'])) {
    $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['datetimepicker']));
    // следующая строка с return вернет json и дальше нее выполнения не будет, 
    // проверьте ее актуальность, ее не должно быть, иначе mysql_query не выполнится
    //return  json_encode(['type'=> 'success', 'mess' => 'Ok']); 
}
else
{
    return  json_encode(['type'=> 'error', 'mess' => 'Not found']);
}
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO datetime(dateandtime) VALUES ('$dataTime')"))
{
  mysql_close();
  return  json_encode(['type'=> 'success', 'mess' => 'Ok']);
}
```

для смены формата `$_POST['datetimepicker']`, можно также использовать класс [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php):

```
$dataTime_date = new DateTime($_POST['datetimepicker']);
$dataTime = $dataTime_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

---

Дополнительно и важно:

- mysql устарело
- никогда (!) не вставляйте получаемые данные без проверки в запрос к базе данных. Используйте подготовленные выражения.

Comment: Не работает ...

Comment: @pointmen23 посмотрите через консоль какие данные вы отправляете, 2 - у Вас return в обоих случаях, записи в бд вообще быть не должно.

Comment: Navigated to http://teset.local/broninp.html?datetimepicker=22.03.2018+14%3A00 все что выдает консоль

Comment: @pointmen23 Вы что-то неправильно делаете, обновили, ответ посмотрите и приведите свой код к такому виду.

Comment: спасибо заработало

Comment: @pointmen23 если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как решение. Для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от ответа, галка станет зеленой, что будет означать, что ответ Вам помог и является решением Вашего вопроса.  [Справка - Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).